# How would I show that $ \forall x \in \mathbb{R^+} \exists n \in \mathbb{N} \text{ s.t } n \leq x < n+1 $ via induction?

Tags: analysis

How would I show that $ \forall x \in \mathbb{R^+} \exists n \in \mathbb{N}  \text{ s.t } n \leq x < n+1 $ via induction?

I have as follows,
I am not allowed to use the Archimedean property yet, but I am allowed to assume that ***for every positive real $x$ there exists an positive integer $n$ such that $n > x$.***

Let 
$P(n):= \exists n \in \mathbb{N^+}\text{ s.t } n \leq x < n+1 \text{ for some } x \in R$

$P(1)$ is true, we take $\sqrt 2.$

Assume the truth of $P(n)$

$P(n+1):=n+1 \leq x < (n+1) +1$

Since $N$ is closed under the operation of adding 1 and the assumption that for every positive real $x$ there exists a positive integer $n$ such that $n > x$, we have the right hand side of the inequality. How would I go about the left hand side?

EDIT

This is been forced, I can't seem to use induction to prove this, for otherwise it is fairly simple.

Comment: The theorem to be proved in your title does not seem to be the same as what you are attempting to prove in your question. You are proving the existence of some $x$ for all $n$, whereas your title asks for the existence of some $n$ for all $x$. (The former seems to lend itself more intuitively to an inductive approach.)

Comment: In the question, $P(n)$ is the statement that *some* $x$ exists such that $n<x<n+1$. Even if we prove $P(1)$ and demonstrate that $P(n+1)$ follows from $P(n)$, we still will have not proved the proposition in the title; we will simply know that there is at least one real number in every (left-closed) interval between natural numbers.

Comment: We want to modify the proposition before attempting to prove it. Let $x=-\pi$.  So either use $\mathbb{Z}$ or specify $x\ge 0$.

Comment: I see, ah I don't know where to go with this.

Comment: I have edited, but i think it has been 'forced'

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't just add one to all three sides of the inequality given by P(n)?

Comment: I am actually in doubt in the way I have defined P(n) :(

Comment: The statement in the title is obviously wrong: if $x$ is negative, you cannot enclose it between positive $n$ and $n+1$. As @AndréNicolas says, either restrict to $x \ge 0$, or pick your $n$ from $\Bbb Z$ instead of $\Bbb N$.

Comment: The current edit is again weird: if $x \in \Bbb R ^+$, then why bother with $\Bbb Z$ and not use just $\Bbb N$? Come on, please, make up your mind!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us first examine the case $x>0$.

For every $N \in \Bbb N \setminus \{0\}$, consider the following statement:

$$P(N) = "\forall x \in [0,N) \ \exists n \in \Bbb N \ (n \le x < n+1)" .$$

Note that $P(1)$ is true, because if $x \in [0,1)$ then $0 \le x < 0+1$, so just pick $n=0$ and be done.

Assume $P(N)$ true and let us prove $P(N+1)$. If $x \in [0,N)$, then $x$ falls under the assumption for $P(N)$, and there is nothing to prove. If $x \in [N, N+1)$, this is equivalent to $N \le x < N+1$, so just pick $n = N$ and this is it.

Therefore, we have proved by induction that for every $x>0$ there exist $n \in \Bbb N \setminus \{0\}$ such that $n \le x < n+1$.

*According to the latest edit of the original question the following part is no longer necessary, but I shall just leave it here.*

Now, if $x \le 0$, then:

- if $x \in \Bbb Z \setminus (\Bbb N \setminus \{0\})$ then just choose $n=x$ to obtain $n = x < x+1 = n+1$, which is true;
- finally, if $x \in (-\infty, 0] \setminus \Bbb Z$ then there exist $n \in \Bbb N \setminus \{0\}$ such that $n \le -x < n+1$, so $-n \ge x > -n-1$. Since $x$ is not an integer, the equality $-n = x$ cannot happen, so let us drop it, while replacing the stronger inequality $x > -n-1$ with the weaker one $x \ge -n-1$, thus obtaining $-n-1 \le x < (-n-1) + 1$, so for $n$ just choose $-n-1$.

Note that nowhere have we used that for every $x$ we can find an $n$ with $n>x$. The only thing used was to make explicit what "belonging to an interval" means.

Comment: The next question I am asked is to prove for $x \in R$ (the first part just being in $R^+$). Sorry about the misleading question, was getting very flustered with this!. A perfect answer! +1

Comment: @HMPARTICLE: For the next question, look at the second half of my answer. The proof is based on the first part, that one is the only place where we use induction.

Answer (score 0):

First, prove the existence of that $n$.

We can do that defining $E:= \{k\in \mathbb{Z} : k\ge x-1\}$

We know that $E$ is not empty because $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}, \exists n\in \mathbb{N} : n>x$.

We have that $E$ is minored by $x-1$ so $E$ has a minimum, let's say $n$.
We have $n\in E$, so $\boxed{n>x-1}$. Since $n-1\notin E$ we have $n-1\le x-1$ if and only if $\boxed{n\le x}$.

Then, if you want to prove the unicity of that $n$

Let's give us $m, n\in \mathbb{Z}$ s.t.

$n\le x< n+1$ and $m\le x< m+1$.

We can combine these inequations to have

$n-m\le x-m< m+1-m = 1$

and

$m-n\le x-n< n+1-n = 1$.

This yields $|m-n|<1$ but $m, n\in \mathbb{Z}$, so $m-n = 0$, i.e. $m=n$

Comment: Thanks, but this is not the problem I have. I have to prove it with an inductive proof.